# ¿Como visualizar imágenes correspondientes a un Array en Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

En el código de abajo inicie las imágenes en un array con una lista de nombres. Quiero que el orden de las imágenes sean alineada con el orden de el array de nombres. Esto es lo que intenté y conseguí un error que dice:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ( code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
>
> **La consola dice:** fatal error: Array index out of range (lldb)
> Code

```
class NonameTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var Names = [" Ferro", "Korean", "HUH?","CatCafe", "UINITY", "FAKESTORE" ,"IRANOUTOFNAMES", "OKAY", "KEEP CODING"]

var Images = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafelois1.jpg"," petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIndentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)


        //configure cell 

         cell.textLabel?.text = Names[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])

            return cell
} 


       override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return Names.count
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que los arrays no tienen la misma cantidad de elementos. El primero tiene 9 y el segundo solo 6. Por lo tanto la línea:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])
```

Te va a dar ese error porque estás intentado acceder a un index del array `Images` que no existe, ya que el máximo al que puedes acceder es `Images.count - 1`. Prueba añadir más nombres al array `Images` o quitar nombres del array `Names` de manera que los dos tengan el mismo número de elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría sería comprobar si en esos índices hay información antes de acceder a ella, por ejemplo:

```
    //configure cell

    if indexpath.row < Names.count {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Names[indexPath.row] 
    }
    if indexpath.row < Images.count {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])
    {

        return cell
```

Por cierto, por convención, los nombres de las variables (Names, Images) deberían empezar en minúscula (names, images) ;)

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Los nombres de las variables SIEMPRE en minúscula (convención camelCase).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en el `Images.xcassets` crees un nuevo grupo con el nombre de cada imagen y añadas ahí las imágenes. Así te quitarías del medio el array `var Images = ["cafedeadend.jpg" .....]` y podrías utilizar el nombre de la imagen como nombre y para llamar a la imagen.